# LoadError: cannot load such file -- actionmailer

Tags: ruby, actionmailer

I'm pretty green when it comes to Gems. So it might be a very obvious error. But could really use some help.

I get the below error when i try "require 'actionmailer'" on irb.

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'actionmailer'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- actionmailer
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
 `require'
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
 `require'
       from (irb):1
       from C:/Ruby200/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

This is the output of the gem env

```
 C:\Users\xxxyyyy\RubyPrac>gem env
 RubyGems Environment:
 - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.14
 - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2014-02-24 patchlevel 451) [i386-mingw32]
 - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
 - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe
 - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby200/bin
 - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
   - ruby
   - x86-mingw32
 - GEM PATHS:
    - C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
    - C:/Users/xxxxyyyy/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
 - GEM CONFIGURATION:
    - :update_sources => true
    - :verbose => true
    - :backtrace => false
    - :bulk_threshold => 1000
 - REMOTE SOURCES:
    - https://rubygems.org/
```

Please help. 
P.S. I'm working on a Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo. Assuming you have it installed (so you have rails or installed it separately), it should be:

```
require 'action_mailer'
```

PS. Do not work on windows with ruby. It will be nothing but pain.

Comment: Oh. that worked. Weird though, because if I do a 'gem list', the name of the gem is 'actionmailer (4.1.6)'